# Glide placeholder doesn't fit the ImageView

Tags: android, android-glide

This is my code

```
 Glide.with(context)
.load(url)
.asBitmap()
.placeholder(resourceId);
.centerCrop()
.into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(imageView) {
      @Override
      protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
          RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
               RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(imageView.getResources(),
               resource);
          circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
          imageView.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
      }
  });
```

Every time I call this function to load users avatar, placeHolder removed and my ImageView is shown as a null background view while url loaded and downloaded image place on ImageView.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What is the image type???

Comment: Which image? placeHolder load a drawable and image view is a imageView

Comment: placeholder image... I mean png or vector???

Comment: something is failing, check your logcat for errors.

Comment: @ShohanAhmedSijan It's a drawable shape

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain there are nothing

Comment: If i got an error, place holder placed successfully

Comment: I think it may something wrong in your drawable shape... First, give another png type image as placeholder to check it...

Answer (score 1):

try overriding onLoadStarted method and inside it set the place holder image.

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .into(new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(imageView) {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable drawable, GlideAnimation anim) {
                        super.onResourceReady(drawable, anim);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
                        super.onLoadFailed(e, errorDrawable);
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadStarted(Drawable placeholder) {
                        super.onLoadStarted(placeholder);
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Give resourceId in load...

```
Glide
 .with(context)
 .load(resourceId)
 .placeholder(resourceId)
 .fitCenter()
 .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(imageView) {
  @Override
  protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
      RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
           RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(imageView.getResources(),
           resource);
      circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
      imageView.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
  }
});
```